# Counting the frequency of 'BB' or 'EE' in a string using Python

Tags: python, string, count

I'm trying to count every time a string appears in a given string

I'm trying to count the number of times 'BB' or 'EE' appear, for example BB would give 1, and BBB would give 2 from '*BB*'B and B'*BB*'. How can I shorten this down? I tried using `count` but it only counts it once.

```
s=input()
for i in range(len(s)+1):
    if i>1:
        if s[i-2:i]=='BB':
            a+=1
        if s[i-2:i]=='EE':
            b+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use regular expression with a positive lookahead for this i think

```
print("FOUND:",len(re.findall("([BE])(?=\\1)",text)))
```

`[BE]` matches either B or E and stores it ... `?=` is a forward lookahead... it requires a match but does not consume it ... `\\1` is saying "match that first thing you stored (either B or E)"

Comment: Wow thanks! I tried using len(re.findall("BB",text))+len(re.findall("EE",text)), but it didn't really work, do you mind if you explain the reasoning behind ([BE])(?=\\1) specifically?

Comment: The lookahead part of the pattern is not consumed for a match, which allows for the overlaps.

Answer (score 0):

```
s=input()
for i,_ in enumerate(s):
    case s[i:i+2]:
        when "BB":
            a += 1
        when "EE":
            b += 1
```

Not tested, though.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat tricky one:

```
a = s.split('B')[1:-1].count('')
b = s.split('E')[1:-1].count('')
```

For example, `'fooBBbarBBBquxB'.split('B')` gives `['foo', '', 'bar', '', '', 'qux', '']`. Splitting by B gives an empty string whenever two consecutive B appear, so I count those empty strings. It also gives an empty string at start/end if the string starts/ends with B, so I remove the first and last element from the list.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Sorry I didn't explain the question that well however it doesn't seem to work sometimes for example, BEEB and BEEE. I don't really understand why though, mind explaining how the code works?

Comment: @EdwardJin Ok I fixed that. Problem was that `split` with explicitly given separator doesn't remove empty strings at start and end (it does when called without separator, i.e., when splitting at all whitespace). Now I'm removing them myself. But I don't like it anymore, this pushed it over an ugliness threshold for me :-)

Comment: Ohhh alright that makes much more sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the last character you saw in the loop, and use it with the current character to test whether you have matched one of your letter pairs.

```
text = input()
lastch = ""
aa = ee = 0
for ch in text:
    test = lastch + ch
    aa += test == "BB"
    ee += test == "EE"
    lastch = ch
```

The character from the last iteration of the loop (`lastch`) is initialized to an empty string, so the first time through, when there's no previous character, `test` doesn't match any of the two-character strings because it only has one character.